# inflection points of the solution of a Cauchy problem

Tags: real-analysis

Prove the solution $y(x)$ of the following Cauchy problem:
\begin{cases} 
y'(x) = x(\frac{\pi}{3}-\arctan y(x)) \\
y(0) = 2
\end{cases}

has inflection points.

I've found $$y''=\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-\arctan y \right) \left(1-\frac{x^2}{{1+y^2}} \right)$$ but how can I find inflection points?

Is $y(x)=\sqrt{x^2-1}$ a curve of inflection points for the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A sufficient condition for existence of an inflection point at $a$

$$
\exists\, k\in\mathbb{N}_{\ge3}:\\\begin{align}&(1)\;y^{(j)}(a)=0\;\forall j=2,3,...,k-1\\
&(2)\;y^{(k)}(a)\neq0\\
&(3)\;k\equiv1\mod2\end{align}
$$

> Proof Strategy

$$
y^{(2)}(x)=\underbrace{(\pi/3-\arctan y)}_{p(x)}\underbrace{\left(1-{x^2\over1+y^2}\right)}_{q(x)}\\
$$
Our inflection point must be a zero of $y^{(2)}$. So we have to prove $y^{(2)}$ vanishes at some point. After that all we have to check is $y^{(3)}$ doesn't vanish at this point i.e. we'll try to make $k=3$ work.

> Lemma A: $y(x)>\sqrt3\;\forall x\implies$$y$ attains global maximum at $x=0$.

Proof: $y(x)>\sqrt3\;\forall x\implies p(x)<0\;\forall x\implies\text{sgn}(y^{(1)})=-\text{sgn}(x)\implies$ $y$ is decreasing for $x>0$ and increasing for $x<0$.

> Lemma B: $y(x)>\sqrt3\;\forall x\implies\exists\, x: y^2+1=x^2$

Proof:
$$\begin{align}
x=0&\implies y^2+1-x^2=5>0\\
x=3&\implies y^2+1-x^2<(y(0))^2+1-9=-4<0\end{align}
$$
Apply intermediate value theorem on the continuous function $g(x)=y(x)^2+1-x^2$.

> $y^{(2)}$ has a zero.

Proof: If $y(x)>\sqrt3\;\forall x$ holds, then $q(x)$ has a zero by lemma B, otherwise $y(z)\le\sqrt3$ for some $z$. If equality holds, $p(z)=0$ otherwise we have $y(0)>\sqrt 3$ and $y(z)<\sqrt 3$ and applying IVT on $y$ we see $\exists z':y(z')=\sqrt3$ and consequently $p(z')=0$.